# How do I create a pandas dataframe in python from a csv with additional delimiters?

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a large csv (on the order of 400k rows) which I wish to turn into a dataframe in python.  The original file has two columns: a text column, followed by an int (or NAN) column.

Example:

```
...
P-X1-6030-07-A01    368963
P-X1-6030-08-A01    368964
P-X1-6030-09-A01    368965
P-A-1-1011-14-G-01  368967
P-A-1-1014-01-G-05  368968
P-A-1-1017-02-D-01  368969
...
```

I wish to additionally split the text column into a series of columns following the pattern of the last three lines of the example text (`P A 1 1017 02 D 01 368969`, for example)

Noting that the text field can have varying formatting (`P-X1` vs `P-X-1`), how might this best be accomplished?

Comment: Additionally, I might want to simply discard or skip over entries in the second format, with extra hyphens in it, rather than having to parse them.

Comment: I see different numbers of hyphens in different rows. The result would not be tabular. A `DataFrame` must have the same number of columns in each row. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: the P-X1 portion could be properly represented either as P-X1 or as P-X-1.  The latter format would be more useful, but the bulk of the data is in the former format. Likewise, the A01 is better represented at A-01, but the majority of the data is in the A01 format.  So the components will need some parsing to make all the data fit properly into the correct buckets.

Comment: I think I have it, would you review my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Attempt**

The spec for `read_csv` indicates that it takes a regular expression, but this appears to be incorrect. After inspecting the source, it appears to merely takes a series of characters that it may use to populate a set of chars followed by `+`, so the below arguments to sep would be used to create a regex like

```
`[- ]+`.
```

Import necessary libs to recreate:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO
```

You can use aset of characters as delimiters, parsing the mismatched rows isn't possible with `pd.read_csv`, but if you want to parse them separately:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO('''P-X1-6030-07-A01    368963
P-X1-6030-08-A01    368964
P-X1-6030-09-A01    368965'''), sep=r'- ') # sep arg becomes regex, i.e. `[- ]+`
```

and

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO('''P-A-1-1011-14-G-01  368967
P-A-1-1014-01-G-05  368968
P-A-1-1017-02-D-01  368969'''), sep=r'- ')
```

But read_csv is apparently unable to use real regular expressions for the separator.

---

**Final Solution**

That means we'll need a custom solution:

```
import re
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''P-X1-6030-07-A01    368963
P-X1-6030-08-A01    368964
P-X1-6030-09-A01    368965
P-A-1-1011-14-G-01  368967
P-A-1-1014-01-G-05  368968
P-A-1-1017-02-D-01  368969'''

fileobj = StringIO.StringIO(txt)

def df_from_file(fileobj):
    '''
    takes a file object, returns DataFrame with columns grouped by 
    contiguous runs of either letters or numbers (but not both together)
    '''
    # unfortunately, we must materialize the data before putting it in the DataFrame
    gen_records = [re.findall(r'(\d+|[A-Z]+)', line) for line in fileobj]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(gen_records)

df = df_from_file(fileobj)
```

and now df returns:

```
   0  1  2     3   4  5   6       7
0  P  X  1  6030  07  A  01  368963
1  P  X  1  6030  08  A  01  368964
2  P  X  1  6030  09  A  01  368965
3  P  A  1  1011  14  G  01  368967
4  P  A  1  1014  01  G  05  368968
5  P  A  1  1017  02  D  01  368969
```

Comment: Perfect.  creating a file object with `containerFile = open('containers.csv','r')` then passing that to `df_from_file()` serves to process a csv residing within the PATH.  Thank you for the answer!